# Django createview m2m not saving

Tags: django

Trying to add the creator of team to the members automatically.
*Team* model has a m2m relationship with *UserProfile* as *members*, here is the code:

```
class CreateTeamView(generic.CreateView):
model = Team
template_name = 'team_create.html'
fields = ('title', 'code', 'coordinator', 'description', 'members')
success_url = '/teams'

def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    if not instance.creator:
        instance.creator = self.request.user.userprofile
        instance.save()
        instance.members.add(instance.creator)
        form.save_m2m()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

But it doesn't work. Team gets created and also the creator is assigned but doesn't get added to members. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, call **.save_m2m()** method of form and run `super().form_valid(form)`, then add new member to instance.
Try this:

```python
if not instance.creator:
    userprofile = self.request.user.userprofile
    instance.creator = userprofile
    instance.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    res = super().form_valid(form)
    instance.members.add(userprofile)
    return res
```

Comment: Sorry no go. I think it is due to `return super().form_valid(form)`. If I inspect form in pdb, it doesn't have the newly added member.

Comment: So if this is problem, let's try my edited code. First call super().form_valid(form) and save return value to "res" variable, then add member to instance, finally return "res".

Answer (score 0):

I removed super() call and added `get_success_url` method instead.

```
if not instance.creator:
        userprofile = self.request.user.userprofile
        instance.creator = userprofile
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        instance.members.add(userprofile)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

It works now.